# Can't get xdebug to work on Win 7 with xampp 1.8.1

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

I am trying to configure Xdebug with xampp 1.8.1.  I have tried to use the wizard with phpinfo() results, but it doesn't seem to work.  The "Download" field is blank.  In phpinfo() all listed extension builds are VC9, and it looks like I need Thread Safe.  I've tried both 32 and 64 bit versions of VC9_TS versions, but nothing seems to work. I am using the php.ini shown on phpinfo)().  I've checked Apache and PHP error logs but there are no related entries.

XDebug Wizard:

```
Summary
Xdebug installed: no
Server API: Apache 2.4 Handler Apache Lounge
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC9 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.4.7
Zend API nr: 220100525
PHP API nr: 20100525
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
Configuration File Path: C:\windows
Configuration File: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Extensions directory: C:\xampp\php\ext
```

Instructions

```
Download
Move the downloaded file to C:\xampp\php\ext
Edit C:\xampp\php\php.ini and add the line
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\
Restart the webserver
```

In php.ini I have the following:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="c:\xampp\tmp>"
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Can you add your phpinfo() that you pasted into the wizard in a zip file, and then attach it to http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=957 ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you rectified the issue ?, if not please try this.
I am having the same situations as yours, and I got result by

1)php.ini file content

```
    zend_extension = "c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll"
    xdebug.remote_autostart=on
    xdebug.remote_enable=on
    xdebug.remote_enable=1
    xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
    ;xdebug.remote_host="localhost:81"
    xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.5
    ;xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
    xdebug.remote_port=9000
    xdebug.remote_mode=req
    xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

here I am using the latest dll, but need to be changed only after testing other changes.

xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.5 - This is the IPv4 address of my system, I changed to this because I couldn't debug with localhost and 127.0.0.1.

in NetBeans IDE, open Tools-> Options->PHP->Debugging. The values of debugger port and Session Id should match with the port and idekey specified in php.ini

Now save php.ini, restart Apache and now try for debugging

Thanks
Johnson